# What's the iOS API for AWS Cognito User Pool Custom Authentication Flow?

Tags: ios, amazon-cognito

Amazon [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html) [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/customizing-your-user-pool-authentication-flow/) outlines how its custom authentication flow works. But there are only passing mentions of iOS.

I have a working authentication system using AWS User Pools and its Custom Authentication Flow using Python Triggers and an iOS Swift app.

But there's a detail still troubling me - see comment after code.

In the `AWSCognitoIdentityCustomAuthentication` handler I've got this:

```
func getCustomChallengeDetails(_ authenticationInput: AWSCognitoIdentityCustomAuthenticationInput, customAuthCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityCustomChallengeDetails>) {

    self.customAuthenticationCompletion = customAuthCompletionSource

    if authenticationInput.challengeParameters.count > 0 {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let code = self.codeTextField.text {
                let details = AWSCognitoIdentityCustomChallengeDetails(
                    challengeResponses: ["CODE" : code])
                details.initialChallengeName = "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE"

                customAuthCompletionSource.set(result: details)
            }
        }
    }

    func didCompleteStepWithError(_ error: Error?) {
        // handling code
    }
}
```

The first call of `getCustomChallengeDetails()` has an empty list for `challengeParameters`. The second call has a correctly populated `challengeParameters`

The method `didCompleteStepWithError(_ error: Error?)` misled me as I thought it only called when an error occurs but is in fact also called on success with `error` set to `nil`.

I also have a UIViewController that prompts the user for a CODE which they've been emailed by my server code. When the user submits the CODE I call this:

```
if let code = codeTextField.text {
        let details = AWSCognitoIdentityCustomChallengeDetails(
            challengeResponses: ["CODE" : code])
        details.initialChallengeName = "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE"

        self.customAuthenticationCompletion?.set(result: details)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

This works. The server code will authenticate users who enter correct CODE values but deny those who submit an incorrect value for CODE.

But why the two `customAuthenticationCompletion?.set(result: details)` calls?
Can anyone say where I've taken a misstep?

Comment: AWS cognito has its own API for authentication, whether its for UserPoolID or IdentitityPoolID.
I have pulled my hair on AWS documentation for 2 weeks at a time, they are so confusing and outdated at times. 
The best way to use AWS for at least ios is to register as a user, use MobileHub to generate a sample project with required API's and use the Wrapper class they generate.

Comment: thanks @SahebRoy for the solidarity. I've taken a look at MobileHub, as you suggested. Unfortunately, the "Email and Password" section doesn't appear to know about AWS's own User Pool custom authentication flows.

Comment: Please give me your email id/skypeid

Comment: You can get me on twitter @CarlHunterRoach